Process are still alive after closing session
I have installed a fresh new MacBook.
There are no third party applications.
I have created 2 users: user1 and user2.
I can switch from user1 to user2 sessions.
I have closed user1 session.
I have typed, in user2 sessions:
ps aux | grep user1

This is strange: I can see some processes !
Why are they still alive ? They should have been killed when closing user1's session ?
Thanks

How did you close user1’s session?  What processes are still alive?

I have closed session from apple menu (top left) and "close session" menu item. I have choose to not reopen applications for next startup in the popup. I can see processes like "mdbulkimport, com.apple.geod, containermanagerd, trustd, lsd, cfprefsd, ..."

In my language (Australian English) I don't have a "close session" menu item. I do have "Log Out xxx" - is that what you mean?  As you have observed, some processes do remain after log out.

Yes i am talking about « log out » menu item. How can we kill those processes automaticaly ? Thanks
